# Java image path on netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, path, imageicon

Im adventuring at Java so Im building a minesweeper. The mechanics are done now I want to make it some user friendly.

Tried to add an ImageIcon to a button on everyway but I cant do it! I dont know how Java works on this!

Im doing this:

(suppose this is extending a JButton)

```
super(new ImageIcon("/minesweeper/resources/bomb.png"));
```

I have packages like this:

- minesweeper
- minesweeper.components
- minesweeper.resources (trying to organize images here)
- test (some stuff for testing only)

Am I doing it wrong? (ofc, but how is it right?)

Answer (score 4):

You can get the images in this way:

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/minesweeper/resources/bomb.png"))
```

Check the Java Doc for [public URL getResource(String name)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I think this is the easiest way.

Comment: Well, its not working. The button is just blank. I think Im still doing it wrong. Ill try the other method too.

Comment: If your problem is how to put an image on the button, check the doc about [button.setIcon(imgage);](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) method.

Comment: Oh, you're right -- that is the easiest way -- I misread the question :) You can just set it directly then.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any problems that may arise, especially when different packaging methods are used, make a new package called `res` or something, then dunk a `Res.java` in it. Put your images in the same package directory. Now, when you want to read something, you'll get the `InputStream` using `Res.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename");`, then create a new ImageIcon with the stream (`new ImageIcon(is)`). This gives you an `ImageIcon` which you can use with the label.

If you want to use the super constructor for setting the image, you can do it in one go:

`super(new ImageIcon(Res.getClass().getResourceAsStream("filename")));`

Otherwise, just use `setIcon(..);`.

Edit: you'll use your existing `resources` package. Just put a `Res.java` in there.